# Laravel 8.x Tailwind Prefix

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, tailwind-css, laravel-pagination

Tailwind allows prefix to be set in `tailwind.config.js`.
[Reference here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix).

I'm working on a Laravel project that uses Bootstrap and Tailwind simultaneously, managed by npm. I've set a prefix "tw-" for Tailwind to prevent classes colliding.

However, Laravel 8.x uses Tailwind by default unless set to use Bootstrap. [Reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap).

Is there any way to let Laravel know about the Tailwind prefix that I set so that it uses the correct Tailwind class names?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it's truly necessary to use both tools for css.

Anyways I'm not entirely sure how you're loading the pagination, but you also have the ability to create your own (custom) pagination view.

**By running the following code:**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

*This command will place the views in your application's resources/views/vendor/pagination directory. The tailwind.blade.php file within this directory corresponds to the default pagination view. You may edit this file to modify the pagination HTML.*

It might suite your needs a lot more to be able to have the pagination view file customized. Because with this you can recreate the pagination using Tailwind (or Bootstrap) classes.